# Create a .NET Core Rest API Application to Support different databases from the Application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, api, rest

I am trying to understand how do I create a RestApi Application in C# with .NET Core 5 to support both SQL Server and MySQL, in future other databases maybe.

I am only using Select Command of sql (Only Read operation)
have complex queries, which requires to join tables and fetch data.
I have challenge in the Query to support both DB.

**SQL Server uses SqlParameter and MySQL uses MySqlParameter** but
the actual select query works for both the database types.

```
        using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"select  * from Table1";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@ID",
            DbType = DbType.Int32,
            Value = ID,
        });
```

Please suggest is there a better way to do it?
I looked in EF Core but couldn't find an exact solution.

Comment: Use OdbcCommand?

Comment: SqlParameter and MySqlParameter derive from the same thing, same with connection, command etc. Using Dapper will also help cut down the amount of code

Comment: @CaiusJard  But DbParameter is an Abstract Class.  Cannot use that instead of SqlParameter or MySqlparameter

Comment: Do you understand how polymorphism works?

Answer (score 1):

A DbCommand has a [`CreateDbParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.createdbparameter?view=net-5.0) that will create an instance of a DbParameter of the correct concrete implementation that matches your DbCommand.

In your code this will be used like this:

```
using var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"select  * from Table1";

var param = cmd.CreateDbParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ID",
param.DbType = DbType.Int32,
param.Value = ID,

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Alternatively use the `CreateDbParameter` method that is found on the [`DbProviderFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory?view=net-5.0) for your database and you get its implementation from [`DbProviderFactories.GetFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories?view=net-5.0)

Info on how to obtain a Factory on Microsofts site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory